# How to define custom Fields with NLog Elasticsearch Target

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, logging, nlog

I'm using this [Elasticsearch Nlog Target](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/) to send my logs to Elasticsearch.  I want to take advantage of Elasticsearch's ability to define specific Fields in an index.  The [Elasticsearch Nlog Target's](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/) docs show examples of field definitions [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki).

I want to do this through code and I want to dynamically set the value of the fields with each message I log.

Looking at things from the Elasticsearch side, I want to see something like this, where I've defined and set the values of two custom Fields, `prop1` and `prop2`:

[image: Event schema]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the assistance of the [Elasticsearch NLog Target's](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/) project [owners](https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets), I found out that the following options exist:

Using NLog's [Fluent API](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-API):

```
_myLogger.Info()
       .Message("your log message.")
       .Property("property1", "value1")
       .Write();

_myTarget.IncludeAllProperties=True;   // Must set on the Elasticsearch target
```

The following syntax is also an option:

```
var myLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
var eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, MyLogger.Name, "Message");
eventInfo.Properties["CustomValue"] = "My custom string";
eventInfo.Properties["CustomDateTimeValue"] = new DateTime(2020, 10, 30, 11, 26, 50);
eventInfo.Properties.Add("CustomNumber", 42);
logger.Log(eventInfo);

_myTarget.IncludeAllProperties=True;
```